# Confused about Gradle delete task

Tags: gradle

I'm currently learning Gradle, so this is probably a simple question but I can't seem to understand.

I need to create a task in my gradle build that deletes a set of intermediate files. So after a bunch of Google'ing, I tried the following:

```
task deleteTest (type: Delete) {
    doLast {
        delete fileTree ('src/main/gen') {
            include '**/*'
        }
    }
}
```

This has no effect, since when I run the task all of the files in the 'src/main/gen' directory still exist. From reading various websites, it seemed like this was the correct approach, but it just doesn't work.

Just for grins, I tried:

```
task deleteTest (type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree ('src/main/gen') {
        include '**/*'
    }
}
```

This seems to work, all of the files get removed from the directory(although it leaves empty sub-directories, which I also don't understand). But from what I read, this is not the correct way to go, since it executes during configuration, not during execution.

Can someone please explain this to me? There's apparently something I'm just not grokking with respect to Gradle in general and this problem in particular.

Comment: doLast will be the last executed task

Comment: Yeah, that I understand. What I don't get is why when using doLast nothing actually executes.

Comment: @MateMrše What do you mean with *"will be the last executed task"*?

Comment: @LukasKörfer I meant, last of the tasks in the build.gradle file.

Comment: This is not correct. The `doLast` closure can be used to run some additional code at the end of the execution of a specific task. It has no impact on the order in which the tasks are executed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **short** answer:

If you just want to delete the folder `src/main/gen` and everything inside, use something like this:

```
task deleteTest(type: Delete) {
    delete 'src/main/gen'
}
```

Your second example is fine, too. It preserves directories because a `fileTree` is used, which only collects files.

The **long** answer:

Your first example mixes the two ways to delete files in Gradle. The first one is to use a task of type `Delete`, the second one is to invoke the method `delete` of the type `Project`. But how to they differ and why are they mixed in your example?

Gradle is based on its task system that allows to define and configure tasks which are only run if necessary. Whether a task is required for the build will be determined from task dependencies (`dependsOn`). This is the reason why Gradle distinguishes between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. During configuration phase, the whole build script gets executed except the actual task actions (not visible in the build script) and code wrapped in `doFirst` / `doLast` closures. During execution phase, each required task gets run by Gradle. This involved executing the `doFirst` closures of the task, then the actual task actions and in the end the `doLast` closures of the task. Now for a `Delete` task like the one above this means, that the code in the configuration closure `delete 'src/main/gen'` gets executed during configuration phase, but the actual deletion of the files (the task action) happens later on, during execution phase.

The problem with this approach arises when its required to delete files directly or all the time (e.g. in a plugin or another scenario). It would be too complicated to create a task, setup the dependencies and so on. Here comes the method `delete` of the type `Project` to the rescue. It provides the same interface for configuration as the task type `Delete`, but executes directly. It can be called via the project instance (e.g. `project.delete 'src/main/gen'`) everywhere in your script and runs instantly, but because the `project` instance is used as scope of the whole script, just using `delete` is sufficient, too. Well, it is not always sufficient. If the current scope provides a method called `delete` (with the same signature), this method will be used instead. This is the case inside a task of type `Delete` and this is the reason why your first script does not work:

Your task of type `Delete` gets configured in the `doLast` closure, which runs **after** the actual deletion should have taken place. If you remove the `type: Delete`, the method `delete` will no longer configure the task, but instead delete the files instantly because it is no longer the method `delete` of the task `Delete`, but the method `delete` of the type `Project`. This works fine, but using a *real* task should be preferred.

If you remove the `type: Delete` from your second example, the same thing will happen. Instead of configuring the task, the files will be deleted instantly (now during configuration phase). You do not want this behavior, because the task will be obsolete, since the files will be deleted every time Gradle is invoked. This is what you mentioned as a possible problem.

Comment: Great explanation. I'm going to have to read it a few times before I finally understand all of it, though :-)